# Is the number prime - SPOJ - error " runtime error (NZEC)"

Tags: java

I'm doing the program for SPOJ.com taks which should recognize Prime number. Unfortunately this SPOJ taks is in Polish language, hence I will try to translate what should be the input and outpu expectation:

**Input:**
n - the number of tests n <100000, in the next lines n numbers from the interval [1..10000]

**Output:**
For each number of the word "YES", if this number is prime. Word: "NO", otherwise.

**Example:**

```
Input:
3
11
1
4

Output:
YES
YES
NO
```

I wrote following code whcih during the test works perfectly fine. Unfortunately when I'm trying to submit this code on SPOJ webpage it is constantly returning me error "
runtime error (NZEC)" Can someone advise how I can improve it?

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();

    if(1<=n&& n<=100000){
        for(int i = 0; i<n+1; i++){
            int v = in.nextInt();
            if(1<=v&&v<=10000){
                if(isPrime(v) == true){
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }
                if(isPrime(v) == false){
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private static boolean isPrime(int v) {
    if (v < 2) return true;
    if (v == 2) return true;
    if (v % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= v; i += 2)
        if (v % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
```

}

Comment: I don't think that your code works fine in tests, because it is wrong: it expects more input than specified with the first number.

Answer (score 1):

Have you learnt Sieve Method for Prime numbers. 
  [Check here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/PrimeSieve.java.html) you will find the better solution.

```
public class PrimeSieve {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // initially assume all integers are prime
        boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[n+1];
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            isPrime[i] = true;
        }

        // mark non-primes <= n using Sieve of Eratosthenes
        for (int factor = 2; factor*factor <= n; factor++) {

            // if factor is prime, then mark multiples of factor as nonprime
            // suffices to consider mutiples factor, factor+1, ...,  n/factor
            if (isPrime[factor]) {
                for (int j = factor; factor*j <= n; j++) {
                    isPrime[factor*j] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // count primes
        int primes = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            if (isPrime[n]) primes++;
        }
        System.out.println("The number of primes <= " + n + " is " + primes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check all numbers from 2 to n, to see if the number isPrime or not.

**Code**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            int v = in.nextInt();
            if (v >= 1 && v < 10000) {
                if (isPrime(v) == true) {
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }
                if (isPrime(v) == false) {
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int v) {
        for(int i=2;i<v;i++) {
            if(v%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: now you can get correct output with the same input. does it fix your problem ?